# Is this a bug or do I really do something wrong?

Tags: excel

Ok, so I have a function **y = (20-(5*x))/2**

I enter values into A:A column, and my B:B column should return Y.

All the values (20, 5, and 2) and references cells with two $ signs (so both row and column are static).

For some reason, when x = 4, my y return is -4E-15 instead of 0 (even though it must be 0, this is just plain math).

[image]

All other Y values are correct. I don't understand what the problem is, and where -0.000000000000003552714 appears from instead of 0.

When I use straight numbers instead of references cells, it works fine. However, this is a problem for my college class, so I will have to change these numbers depending on the problem set, so it is much more convinient for me to use cell reference.

The formula for my second column (which is Y) is: =($N$4-($N$2*A47))/$N$3
where N4 = 20, N2 = 5, N3 = 2.

The problem seems to be with my X column. Instead of typing 3, 3.1, 3.2 etc., I use a formula **A2 = A1 + 0.1** If I change it to plain numbers, it works fine. But I don't understand the issue here.

Comment: This is floating point error.  You will want to round it to the decimal point you want.

Comment: Thank you. So it's kinda a bug then.